# how can I check if a structure is in the array of structures based on its field in Swift3?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, contains

In my `swift` app I have a structure:

```
open class MyStruct : NSObject {

    open var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    open var username: String? = ""
    open var id: String? = ""
}
```

And I create an Array of it:

```
var array:[MyStruct] = []
```

Then I'm creating an object:

```
let pinOne = MyStruct()
pinOne.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: request.latitude, longitude: request.longitude)
pinOne.username = request.username
pinOne.id = request.id
```

and I want to add it to the array only if the array does not contain it. I tried with this:

```
if(!(self.array.contains(pinOne))){
    self.array.append(pinOne)
}
```

But it didn't work, so I thought that since I have unique `id`s, I could use that field for comparing objects. But I don't know how to compare fields of the structures in this case. Can you help me with that?

Comment: A class named `MyStruct`? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating object of `MyStruct` before checking its existence you need to create only if its not exist in `Array`. Also as a suggestion create one `init` method in the `MyStruct` like `init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String, id: String)` will reduce your code of initialization of every instance property in new line.

```
open class MyStruct : NSObject {

    open var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    open var username: String? = ""
    open var id: String? = ""

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String, id: String) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.username = name
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

Now Check for contains like this.

```
if !array.contains(where: {$0.id == request.id}) {
    let pinOne = MyStruct(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: request.latitude, longitude: request.longitude), name: request.username, id: request.id)
    self.array.append(pinOne)
}
```

Comment: how to get index of searched array element?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(array.contains({$0.id==pinOne.Id}))
{
   array.addElement(pinOne);
}
```

Comment: hm, just to make sure - if I want to add an element if it is `not` in the array, then I need to use the if(`!`(array.contains({$.id==pinOne.Id}))), right?

Comment: also, my compiler (in `swift 3`) raises an error that `$` is unresolved :|

Answer (score 0):

Shorter & simpler:

```
if array.index(where: {$0.id == pineOne.id}) == nil {
   array.append(pineOne)
}
```

Comment: I think the correct syntax is `== false`, not `nil`.