# Check item contains in model object array in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3

I have a model object called user.
 how to find my user.id from all users collection.
I need something like this `UsersCollection.contains(user.id)`
 and returns Bool value.

Comment: I tried this but got error "Type 'UsersCollection' has no subscript members"

Comment: That link have array of dictionary check this one [how can I check if a structure is in the array of structures based on its field in Swift3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518705/how-can-i-check-if-a-structure-is-in-the-array-of-structures-based-on-its-field)

Comment: Compare your specific unique property like `if UsersCollection.contains(where: {$0.id == user.id}) {`

Comment: Is there any way to get other properties of UsersCollection object here? I need to get name

Comment: @NiravD If that object matches I need to get the name from [UsersCollection]. can i access something like $0.name from the collection?

Comment: Then what you are looking for is `first(where:)` like I have suggested my first solution,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43522346/get-element-from-array-of-dictionaries-according-to-key But instead of subscription simply access property same way you have done in contains after that inside if let access the name property for that user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144818/discussion-between-vinu-david-jose-and-nirav-d).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go.

```
let contains = UsersCollection.contains{ $0.id == 0 }
```

Edit:

```
let object = UsersCollection.first{ $0.id == 0 } // object is optional here.
```

Comment: here how I can access properties of that particular user object in UsersCollection ?

Comment: Check my edit above.